# How do I correctly set a background image to a pop up window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to set a background image to a pop up menu in javascript, I have seen a lot of answers but none it is working for me. I do not know If I correctly write the path of the image, I think it is fine. The data is loaded inside the pop up windows is through ajax, so I try to put php code with html to set the background but it is not working. Please help I am stuck

This is my code :

```
$.post('nacimientos/controller/controllerGuardarNacimiento.php',{'nss':nss, 'nombre':nombre, 'apellidos':apellidos, 'sexo':sexo, 'peso':peso, 'talla': talla, 'hora':hora}, function(data){
        var left  = ($(window).width() / 2) - (900 / 2);
        var top   = ($(window).height() / 2) - (600 / 2);

        WinId = window.open('', 'newwin', 'width=900,height=800,scrollbars=0, menubar=0,top= ' + top + ', left='+left);
        WinId.document.open();
        WinId.document.writeln("<body style='background-image: url('imagen3.jpg')'>");
        WinId.document.write(data);
        WinId.document.writeln("<\/body>");
        WinId.document.close();


    });
```

The other code is the data that is loaded in the pop up is :

```
echo "<div align='center'>";
echo "<h1>Felicidades!!</h1>";
echo "</div>";

echo "<div align='center'>";
foreach($resultado2 as $value){
            echo "<label for=''><h3>Nacimiento no: </h3></label><h3>".$value['id_nacimiento']."</h3>";
            echo "<label for=''><h3>N&uacute;mero de Seguridad Social (NSS):</h3></label><h3>".$value['nss']."</h3>";
            echo "<label for=''><h3>Nombre:</h2></label><h3>".$value['nombre']." ".$value['apellidos']."</h3>";
            echo "<label for=''><h3>Sexo:</h3></label><h3>"; if($value['sexo'] == 'm'){ echo "Hombre";} else{ echo "Mujer";} echo "</h3>";
            echo "<label for=''><h3>Peso:</h3></label><h3>".$value['peso']." "."gramos</h3>";
            echo "<label for=''><h3>Talla:</h2></label><h3>".$value['talla']." "."cm</h3>";
            echo "<label for=''><h3>Hora de nacimiento:</h3></label><h3>".$value['hora']."</h3>";
}
echo " </div>";
?>
```

My js is called funcionesNacimientos.js, and my directory is like this
[image]

this is the body tag

[image]

Comment: Is everything else working? Can you access the image on path http://[yourserver.com]/imagen3.jpg?

Comment: @Senthe yes everything, when I use firebug the html is displayed as <body imagen3.jpg')'="" style="background-image: url(">

Comment: You should be able to tell if this is a problem with the path by looking at your browser's dev tool (F12).  Look at the network tab for resources failing to load.

Comment: it is empty, it seems there is no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refer to the relative path, and fix the quotes problem by escape them in `style='background-image: url('imagen3.jpg')'`, so it should be :

```
..."<body style='background-image: url(\'js/img/imagen3.jpg\')'>"...
```

You could also try `background` attribute :

```
..."<body background='js/img/imagen3.jpg'>"...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for answering but It is not working I wrote: WinId.document.writeln("<body style='background-image: url('js/img/imagen3.jpg')'>");

Comment: ur welome, plz check if there's any messages in the log in your browser console.

Comment: So the problem not comming from image.

Comment: I think so, I do not know the problem

Comment: is there any other way to set up the background image?

Comment: You're welcome, are you sure the first doesn't work with quote escaping `\'`, else how your html looks like?

Comment: Please post the body tag code located in your browser inspector.

Comment: thanks for answering I found the the only way that it works is: WinId.document.writeln("<body style='background-image: url(nacimientos/view/js/img/imagen3.jpg);'>"); do you know why?

Comment: Not sure why, are you using any framework? and from where the `funcionesNacimientos.js` was called?

Comment: No I am not using any framework, the funcionesNacimientos.js is called in index.php (outside of all the directories), I think maybe that is the reason?, thanks for your help